# html5 video in Internet Explorer 10 with files hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-10

Please point out to me the error of my ways...

here is the code...

```
 //NOTE: That is not the real source URL. It has been edited for brevity
<video controls>
    <source src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/...The+Offering+Section+3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This works in both Chrome, and Firefox, but IE 10 gives an error of "Invalid Source".

Would it have anything to do with the `+` stringing the URL together instead of the standard `-`...

From what I understand, the above solution is supposed to be supported by IE 10. Or am I mistaken?

EDIT: The files are hosted on Amazon S3, and served through their CDN.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639444/how-do-i-get-a-html5-video-to-work-using-ie10

Comment: yep...already been there before asking this question...its a no-go

Comment: @OneOfOne, could you please remove the duplicate question status, as this question is NOT a duplicate of the question asked by your reference. I looked at that question numerous times before asking this question, and the fixes proposed by the answers there DID NOT provide me an answer. I've made changes to the question that specifically address my issue more clearly, which is, I believe, an altogether different use-case than the question posed by the post you referred me to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it's because of the url. IE should read mpeg4 videos, then maybe like Safari mobile, a bug with some mpeg configurations (bitrate...etc.) http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/09/30/how-to-encode-video-for-mobile-use/

Comment: The issue was that the MIME type set in S3 needed to be switched to `video/mp4`. After I did that, everything worked great.

Comment: I concur with @RebelPheonix. I had this exact problem, IE10 not playing mp4 video hosted on Amazon S3. As soon as I changed the MIME type to video/mp4 it worked. To change the MIME type, select the video in S3, click 'Properties', expand 'Metadata', type in video/mp4 in the Value field next to Content-Type. Click save and your externally hosted video should now play just fine.

Comment: same here... but then I was looking for video/mp4 in the drop-down, realizing there's none... of course I didn't realize for about an hour I could just put the cursor there and literally type it in myself... all good now, watching the video on IE10 :)