# Browserstack Win7 IE10 not playing HTML5 videos

Tags: testing, windows-7, internet-explorer-10, browserstack

I've been building a website that uses HTML5 video. I started testing with Browserstack and everything looked good, until I got to Windows 7 IE10. Any video element simply wont load the .mp4 on Browserstack. It just shows a blank screen.

Examples of sites when testing:

http://html5demos.com/video

http://www.videojs.com/

Has anyone experienced this on Browserstack or is this a real Windows 7 IE10 issue?

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem. The native player in Win7/IE10 on Browserstack simply does not seem to want to work. (The demos of several popular players do not work.)

Comment: I'm seeing this, too. Has anyone tried contacting Browserstack? I'm thinking the issue may be because [Windows Media Player is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912311/382982) from this VM image.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same problem and contacted Browserstack.

They are aware about the problem and looking for a way to fix it (it is not as simple as somebody forgot to install something). Currently it works fine on Win 8 in IE10.

This is not a real issue on windows 7 in IE10.

Comment: You have GOT to be kidding....I've been debugging this all day. [closes laptop and goes to bed]

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack has acknowledged this as an issue when testing IE 10 and 11 on Windows 7.

> HTML5 videos work on all remote browsers, with the exception of Internet Explorer 10 and 11 on Windows 7.

Source: https://www.browserstack.com/question/649

HTML5 video does play fine on Windows 7 with IE 10 and 11. I can also confirm [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) doesn't have any issues playing video.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is not related to Browserstack Win7 IE10 , even on physical machine i am facing this problem . This is due to Content type add these.

If your hosting is served on a Linux/Apache web server, often you can add MIME types to an .htaccess file and upload it to your remote site's root folder.

Video:-

```
 AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
 AddType video/ogg .ogv
 AddType video/webm .webm
```