# Slick Slider play video by clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, slick.js

I have slider and each slider contains video as background and play/pause buttons. Trying to play video by clicking proper button, but I get this behavior: I click play button from the second slide and video plays from the first slide. The same is for pause button. Advice please how can I fix this bug?

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('play'), function(element, index) {
  element.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('video')[index].play();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7u78vwaq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your fiddle. There is a bug in the way you are adding executing click callback. Based on the code you have, replace

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[index].play();
```

by

```
$(this).siblings().closest('video')[0].play();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE10 :(
Tried polyfills, jquery .each() method, but nothing works

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639444/how-do-i-get-a-html5-video-to-work-using-ie10